OpenBrush and RMRK-Ink updates?
I had been looking around for tools to aid my ink! smart contract development. I had found OpenBrush from BrushFam and RMRK-ink to be a great resources.But seem like they haven't got any updates since last year. Does those projects getting no more maintance. If so is there an alternative?

Please join the https://t.me/onpopio, we are building a chain for ink! smart contracts and would be happy to answer any questions you have!
